# How to export proxy in Redhat Linux 7 using the current login credentials?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, proxy

I need to export proxy on RHEL 7 with the current logged user credentials.

I am able to achieve this by adding manually in **.bashrc or .bash_profile.**:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.com:6080
export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.com:6080
```

The above method works fine. But I don't want this method, since we are hard-coding the username and password and also it's not secure.

Is it possible to use the existing **/etc/shadow** file as password for exporting the proxy?

Comment: An HTTP proxy does not work like that. Shadow passwords are also in a very different format.

Answer (score 0):

You could place something like the following as a script in /etc/profile.d/ directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
    if [ $SHLVL = 1 ]; then
    echo -n "Enter proxy password:"
    read -sr mypass
    export http_proxy="http://$USER:$mypass@proxy.example.com:6080"
    export https_proxy=$http_proxy
    echo
fi
```

`if [ $SHLVL = 1 ]` will prevent the script from running when spawning subshells such as when starting script for logging.

`read -s` will prevent echoing input as password is typed.

`$USER` is an environment variable that is the current username.

The final `echo` just prints a newline to get the next prompt on the next line.

Comment: Again you are hardcording the password,  if we type "`env`" command the password is blind open. I don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is requiring username/password authentication when connecting to the proxty. One way or another, you will need to set the username and password somewhere when connecting to the proxy.

There is a reason why the [proxy PAC configuration file format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file) does not include password authentication.

## Set the password within application

Instead of setting the proxy URL in the bash environment, you need to define the proxy URL on a per application basis. For example, for installing Redhat packages, you can define the proxy in `/etc/yum.conf` or any of the `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` files.

Likewise for web browsers, set the proxy URL within the browser's settings.

## Proxy chaining

Run a local proxy that does not accept password, but when it connects to the actual, upstream proxy, you can define the username and password.

Use a tool such as [proxy-login-automator](https://github.com/sjitech/proxy-login-automator)